# How to deal with getImageData at bounds in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, html5-canvas, getimagedata

I'm currently writing a little drawing application that needs to access pixel data for its smudge and blur tools and bumped into a nasty issue with HTML5 Canvas API in Firefox. Apparently it does not implement getImageData quite as defined in the spec. The [spec specifically says](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-getimagedata) "... Pixels outside the canvas must be returned as transparent black. ...".

This doesn't happen in FF (tested in FF 3.6 and 4 beta 9). Instead it will give an error such as this: An invalid or illegal string was specified" code: "12

Note that this appears to work in Chrome just fine.

I guess this means I will have to implement some extra code to work around this limitation.  I managed to bypass the issue using the following code:

```
            getImageDataAround: function(p, r) {
                p = this._toAbsolute(p);
                r = this._toAbsolute(r);

                p = p.sub(r);

                var d = r * 2;
                var width = d;
                var height = d;

                // XXX: FF hack
                if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1) {
                    if(p.x < 0) {
                        width += p.x;
                        p.x = 0;
                    }

                    if(p.y < 0) {
                        height += p.y;
                        p.y = 0;
                    }

                    var x2 = p.x + width;
                    if(x2 >= this.width) {
                        width = d - (x2 - this.width);
                    }

                    var y2 = p.y + height;
                    if(y2 >= this.height) {
                        height = d - (y2 - this.height);
                    }

                    if((width != d) || (height != d)) {
                        // XXX: not ideal but at least this won't give any
                        // errors
                        return this.ctx.createImageData(d, d);
                    }
                }

                return this.ctx.getImageData(p.x, p.y, width, height);
            },
```

This isn't cool since I return bunch of empty pixels to the caller. It would be way nicer to return results just like in the spec.

Just to clarify the code is a part of a Context API that wraps real context and provides some extra functionality (relative coords etc.). That probably explains where things like this.width etc. come from.

It's the XXX part that's troublesome. I simply need some way to return ImageData that's up to spec. Any ideas on how to do this are welcome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could create a canvas of size d by d and draw the appropriate portion of the original canvas on to it? Sadly you can't draw the original canvas directly because you run into the same sort of bounds-checking code, so you have to figure out the overlap.

You should consider sniffing for [Gecko](http://geckoisgecko.org/) rather than Firefox.

By the way, this is Mozilla [bug 392751](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=392751).

Comment: Yeah. I guess there's no other way... It's a shame they haven't fixed it yet (bug report is from 2007!). I'm going to keep this question open for a while to get some other ideas. If nothing comes around, I'll accept your answer. :) Good point about sniffing!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using following snippet to work around the issue. Hopefully someone finds it useful...

```
var getImageDataAround = function(ctx, p, r) {
    // ctx: HTML5 Canvas 2D context
    // p: {x: 23, y: 37}
    // r: radius in px

    // FF fails with fractional values
    p.x = Math.round(p.x);
    p.y = Math.round(p.y);
    r = parseInt(r);

    p.x -= r;
    p.y -= r;

    var d = r * 2;
    var width = d;
    var height = d;

    // FF fails at bounds
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Gecko') != -1) {
        var xOffset = 0;
        var yOffset = 0;

        if(p.x < 0) {
            xOffset = -p.x;
            width += p.x;
            p.x = 0;
        }

        if(p.y < 0) {
            yOffset = -p.y;
            height += p.y;
            p.y = 0;
        }

        var x2 = p.x + width;
        if(x2 >= ctx.canvas.width) {
            width = d - (x2 - ctx.canvas.width);
        }

        var y2 = p.y + height;
        if(y2 >= ctx.canvas.height) {
            height = d - (y2 - ctx.canvas.height);
        }

        if((width != d) || (height != d)) {
            var data = ctx.createImageData(d, d);

            if(xOffset >= d || yOffset >= d ||
                    width < 1 || height < 1) {
                // totally outside of bounds
                return data;
            }

            var originalData = ctx.getImageData(p.x, p.y,
                width, height);
            var pos = 4 * (xOffset + d * yOffset);
            var dataLen = 4 * d * (yOffset + height);

            for(var originalPos = 0, x = xOffset;
                    pos < dataLen;
                    pos += 4, originalPos += 4, x++) {
                if(x == d) {
                    x = xOffset;
                    pos += xOffset * 4;
                }

                if(xOffset <= x && x < width + xOffset) {
                    data.data[pos] = originalData.data[originalPos];
                    data.data[pos + 1] = originalData.data[originalPos + 1];
                    data.data[pos + 2] = originalData.data[originalPos + 2];
                    data.data[pos + 3] = originalData.data[originalPos + 3];
                }
                else {
                    originalPos -= 4;
                }
            }

            return data;
        }
    }

    return ctx.getImageData(p.x, p.y, width, height);
}
```